# Audio visualization by GautamChibde

Tags: java, android, audio, rendering, visualization

I wanted to use the audio viewer made by GautamChibde
https://github.com/GautamChibde/android-audio-visualizer
But in the rendering I can't see it. It gives me this error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:android.media.audiofx.Visualizer$OnDataCaptureListener

Anyone by any chance know where the problem is ???

[image]

build.gradle :
[image]

activity.xml :

```
<com.chibde.visualizer.SquareBarVisualizer
    android:id="@+id/visualizer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"/>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

do you try rstart IDE for your android studio or clicked repair IDE in 5 steps for ur project? if you don't that :

```
 1- click file tab 
 2-then Restart IDE and reopen it 
 3- and if not fix and show click file
 4- Repair IDE in 5 steps in down your split layout if not fix
 5- click Invalidate Cashes and Restart in the same file tab
```